# Example of weakly convergent sequence, not convergent in norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence

I need to find example of sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $C[a,b]$ which converges weakly to $f \in C[a,b]$, such that $||f_n||_u \to ||f||_u, n \to \infty$, where $$||f||_u = \underset{x \in [a,b]}{max }|f(x)|,$$ but $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ doesn't converge to $f$ in norm.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $[a,b] = [0,1]$ and take for $f_n$ function which is:
a. 1 at 0 
b. 0 at $\frac{1}{2n}$ 
c. 1 at $\frac{1}{n}$ 
d. 1 at 1 
e. and linear between these points 
The weak limit of $f_n$ is function which is identically $1$
since we have point-wise convergence and functions are bounded.
At the same time the norm of the difference is $1$.